# ElasticSearch multi_match query for array of strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to query 3000 data from ElasticSearch, and currently I am using multi_match for querying. Is there a way to match using an array of strings? Term is not usable as it only queries the exact value of the string.

Below is an example of an ideal request:

```
{

    "size": 1,
    "_source": ["_id"],
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": ["val1", "val2"],
            "fields": [
                "name",
                "url"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Another use case would be like searching schools:

```
{

    "size": 1,
    "_source": ["_id"],
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": ["school name 1", "school name 2"],
            "fields": [
                "name"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Consider the spaces of each values to be the whole school name.

Answer (score 1):

`multi_match` doesn't accept and array of values but nothing prevents you from sending a string containing the values. The query string will be analyzed into two tokens `val1` and `val2` and each will be matched separately on each field.

```
{

    "size": 1,
    "_source": ["_id"],
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "val1 val2",
            "fields": [
                "name",
                "url"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way that ElasticSearch has similar query like SQL that can compare the column's value from a list? eg: SQL's `=ANY()` or `IN` operator?

Comment: That's what the above query does under the hood, you just need to concatenate the array into a space separated string

Comment: What if the values have spaces in them? Are there any way to have separators in each values considering most values have two or more words? I'm still new to ElasticSearch

Comment: It would help to know your use case, because there are different ways of achieving what you want, but it depends on what you actually need. Feel free to expand on your use case

Comment: Just edited my question. My problem is that I need to query school names from ElasticSearch and I think that querying those schools as a form of list of values would be faster and more efficient.

Comment: That changes the focus a bit... Now I'm curious to know why you don't want to search by exact names since that seems to be what you're after?

Comment: Well, the original values that needs to be queried to ElasticSearch came from the db and has some slightly different separators to the response of ElasticSearch and we need to know those differences. I just thought that forming those data from the db into list and then query it into ElasticSearch will be more efficient than querying the values one by one

Comment: Ok, but what makes you think that you cannot use the `terms` query? Can you give an example?

Comment: I think `terms` queries the values exactly and since that there some slight differences to the data from the db to ElasticSearch's response, some data will not be returned. That's why I currently use `match`. I'm still new to ElasticSearch and haven't dug deep yet

Comment: Can you show a quick example of those "slight differences"?

Comment: Okay. For example, in the the db, the data is `School Name 1 Location` and in ElasticSearch the response for the `name` is `School Name 1 - Location`. Tried it in `terms` query and it didn't work since they don't exactly match.

Comment: Where does this `-` come from if ES has been sourced from DB?

Comment: Hi, I just created an API function that calls the query based on the parameters and loops it per parameter value. Kinda inefficient, but solved my problem. Thanks!